# Guardar preferencias con SharedPreferences en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, sharedpreferences

Mi problema es el siguiente: tengo un EditText y un TextView donde se copian las vocales que yo pongo en el EditText. El caso es que necesito que con SharedPreferences al pausar o parar la aplicación lo que hay escrito en el TextView (las vocales) sigan estando ahí. He estado un rato dandole vueltas y no se que tengo mal. Si podeis echarme una mano lo agradecería un montón. Adjunto el código de mi clase MainActivity.java Tengo que añadir que haciendo pruebas anteriores he comprobado que en el archivo que se guardan esos datos no se me almacenaban los datos de tipo String pero si los de tipo numérico. No entiendo el mecanismo por el que guardan un tipo de datos y otros no.

```
    package com.dani.vocalesapp;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    
        SharedPreferences.Editor miEditor;
        SharedPreferences misDatos;
        EditText campoB;
        TextView campoC;
        String vocales;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            campoB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campotextoB);
            campoC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campotextoC);
            // Abre un fichero de prefrerencias (El parametro 0 indica privado)
            misDatos = getSharedPreferences("preferencias",0);
            miEditor = misDatos.edit();
            vocales=misDatos.getString("vocales",campoC.getText().toString());
            Button botonBorrar = findViewById(R.id.botonBorrar);
            botonBorrar.setOnClickListener(this);
            botonBorrar.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
    
            class KeyListener implements View.OnKeyListener {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    // mediante comprobaciones vemos con ACTION_DOWN (pulsar tecla) que tecla se pulsa (KEYCODE_?) y añadimos esa vocal a los dos campos de texto
                    if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A)){
                        campoB.append("a");
                        campoC.append("a");
                        return true;
                    } else if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E)){
                        campoB.append("e");
                        campoC.append("e");
                        return true;
                    } else if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I)){
                        campoB.append("i");
                        campoC.append("i");
                        return true;
                    } else if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O)){
                        campoB.append("o");
                        campoC.append("o");
                        return true;
                    } else if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_U)){
                        campoB.append("u");
                        campoC.append("u");
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
            View.OnKeyListener listener = new KeyListener();
            campoB.setOnKeyListener(listener);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            // extrae el contenido de las vacales del campo C
            vocales = campoC.getText().toString();
            miEditor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Preferencias guardadas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            vocales = campoC.getText().toString();
            miEditor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Preferencias guardadas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           campoC.setText("");
           campoB.setText("");
           vocales=misDatos.getString("vocales","");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de guardar los cambios debes ingresar los valores a la preferencia usando el método `putString()`, de esta forma se guardaran sin problema.

```
 ... 
 vocales = campoC.getText().toString();
 miEditor.putString("vocales", vocales); //* Guarda valor en preferencia 
 miEditor.apply();
 ...
```

Comment: He añadido el método y sigue sin funcionarme.

Comment: El guardado va a ocurrir únicamente cuando envíes a segundo plano o cierres la app.